# Why my find and select code selects all text in Word?

Tags: c#, select, ms-word, find, wildcard

I'd like to find and select all text in a Word document, using C#, that is between brackets. But it selects all text instead.

Here is the full code for this part:

```
private void StartAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in fileLIST.Items)
    {

        // Open + activate Word
        Word._Application word_app = new Word.Application();

        //visible or not
        word_app.Visible = true;

        word_app.Documents.Open(item.ToString());



        Word.Range range = word_app.ActiveDocument.Content;
        Word.Find find = range.Find;

        find.MatchWildcards = true;
        find.Text = "\[*\]";
        find.Forward = true;
        find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
        find.ClearFormatting();


        find.Execute();


        // unhide hide all
        range.Font.Hidden = 1;  // 1 = False


        // Save and close
        word_app.ActiveDocument.Save();


        object SaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges;
        word_app.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Square brackets indicate a character range when using wildcards. To match actual bracket characters, you need to escape them `\[`. Apart from that: Is your text enclosed in single or double brackets? Simply `[text]` or `[[text]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find text in simple brackets, the bracket characters must be escaped; and instead of selecting the range you need to execute the find. ;-):

```
word_app.Documents.Open(item.ToString());

Word.Range range = word_app.ActiveDocument.Content;
Word.Find find = range.Find;

find.MatchWildcards = true;
find.Text = @"\[*\]";
find.ClearFormatting();
find.Execute();
while (find.Found)
{
    // unhide hide all
    range.Font.Hidden = 1; // 1 = F
    find.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Ahh... I may need to escape with double \\.

Comment: Did it throw that error before you tried the above code or now? Because this one totally should work.

Comment: It works if: " \ \ [ * \ \ ] " ;

However, for some reason, it will only make one successful pass. I mean, it applies the additional task (formatting) only on the first occurence of the found result.

Comment: For that you need some sort of loop of course. e.g. `While(find.Found) { }`
I cannot simply edit my code above though. For that I would need more input from you / your attempt in order to help you correct your code.

Comment: OK, edited my code to reflect this. Untested, mind you!

Answer (score 0):

`"\[*\]"` should have been  `"\\[*\\]"`.